# Finding an expression for a multi variate joint CDF.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ and $Z$ be random variables with $X$ and $Y$ dependent, and $Z$ independent of both $X$ and $Y$. Let  $f_{X},f_{Y},f_{Z}$  denote the density function's of $X,Y$ and $Z$ respectively and $f_{X,Y}$ denote the joint density function of $X$ and $Y$.

Assuming the support of all three random variables is $[0,\infty]$, we can give an expression for $\mathbb{P}[Z>f(Y),Y<b],\;\mathrm{with}\;b\in[0,\infty),$ as:

$\mathbb{P}[Z>f(Y),Y<b] = \int_{y=0}^{b}\int_{z=f(y)}^{\infty}f_{Z,Y}dzdy = \int_{y=0}^{b}\int_{z=f(y)}^{\infty}f_{Z}f_{Y}dzdy.$

The above problem is $fairly$ trivial. We now form a new, more complicated, problem by introducing $X$. The new problem looks like this:

Given the definitions of $X,Y$ and $Z$ above, can we find an expression for:

$\mathbb{P}[Z>f(X,Y),X+Y<b]\;?$

Comment: What is the meaning of $\int_{z=f(y)}^{\infty}\int_{y=0}^{b}\ldots dydz$?

Comment: @Did , are you concerned with the fact that I did not define a joint density function for $Z$ and $Y$ ?

Comment: No, rather by the fact that I would not know how to compute a double integral written in this order.

Comment: @Did. Sorry, yes I spotted this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the expression you want, you will need the support for the joint p.d.f. of $X$ and $Y$ (i.e. the set of $(x,y) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ for which $f_{X,Y} \neq 0$). For convenience I will let the support be given by $[u,v] \times [c,d]$ for some real numbers $u < v, c < d$.

Since $Z$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$, we have that the joint p.d.f. of $X, Y,$ and $Z$ is given by $f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = f_{X,Y}(x,y)f_Z(z)$ and so $$\mathbb{P}[Z>f(X,Y) \cap X+Y<b] = \int_u^v\int_c^{b-x}\int_{f(x,y)}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)f_Z(z) \; dz \; dy \; dx$$

So it's a similar procedure to the one you already have. You start by integrating $f_{X,Y,Z}$ over all values of $z$ for which $z > f(x,y)$, and then you integrate over the region for which $x + y < b$. That is, you integrate first over all $y$ for which $c < b - x$, and then over all possible values of $x$.

If something about this is unclear or straight-up wrong, let me know and I'll try to correct :)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful. One can also note that, since $Z$ is independent of both $X$ and $Y$, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ can be factored out of the innermost integral, leaving the innermost integral as the complementary CDF:


$\mathbb{P}[Z > f(x,y)].$

Comment: Should the outermost integral be taken from $u$ to $b$? If not - why?

Comment: Hi Dave, sorry that I got back to you so late - my activity here can be a little sporadic. Looking back at this problem, I think you do not integrate from $u$ to $b$. Think about the region $R$ over which you are integrating $(x,y)$ - on your $x$-axis you go from $u$ to $v$, and on your $y$-axis you go from $c$ to $d$. There is also the line $y = b - x$, and since we want $x + y < b$, the region of interest is therefore the area between the axes and underneath the line. So depending on what order you want to integrate in, you either go from $c \le y \le b -x $ (not all the way to $d$),

Comment: and then from $u \le x \le v$; or in the other direction from $u \le x \le b - y$ and then $c \le y \le d$. If you draw this out, you'll see that in both cases, you integrate over the entire correct area. To directly address your question, if you integrated from $u$ to $b$, it is possible that you are either covering more than the area $R$ or less than it, depending on the value of $b$. Let me know if something is unclear. Again, sorry for late response.